# AngularJS - how to update variable on $scope after JSON returns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm new in angular and I'm working on a project that depends on service and factories. my problem is when I'm using a static jason array for response, the variables are filled correctly and are shown in view, but when I change it to a ajax request and get it from a json file, the response comes successful but the controller variables are not successfully loaded with data.

this is my angular project structure:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('mytestapp',['ngRoute'])
  .config(config)
  .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl)
  .controller('AboutCtrl', AboutCtrl)
  .factory('GeneralInit', GeneralInit)
  .service('UserSrv', UserSrv);
  GeneralInit.$inject = ['UserSrv','$q'];
  HomeCtrl.$inject = ['GeneralInit','$timeout','UserSrv'];
```

and here are my config:

```
    function config($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'template/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'hmc',
            resolve: {
              GeneralInit: function(GeneralInit){
                return GeneralInit();
              }}
        })
        .when('/about', {
          templateUrl: 'template/about.html',
          controller: 'AboutCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'abc',
          resolve: {
            GeneralInit: function(GeneralInit){
              return GeneralInit();
            }}
        });
    }
```

here is my service:

```
function UserSrv($http) {
  var User={};
  var service = {
    getUser: Get,
    updateUser: Update,
    logoutUser: Logout
  };
  return service;

  function Get() {
    //return {"FirstName":"StaticName","LastName":'StaticLastName'}
    $http.get('/user.json')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          User = data;
          console.log(User);
          return User;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      })
  }

  function Update() {

  }

  function Logout() {

  }

}
```

My controller and initialize item:

```
function GeneralInit(UserSrv,$q)
{
  return function() {
    var User = UserSrv.getUser(); //{'FirstName':'FstName','LastName':'LstName'};//
    var Base='browser';

    return $q.all([User, Base]).then(function(results){
      return {
        User: results[0],
        Base: results[1]
      };
    });
  }
}

function HomeCtrl(GeneralInit,$timeout)
{
  var hmc= this;
  $timeout(function(){
      hmc.User=GeneralInit.User;
      console.log(hmc.User);
    }
  ,0);
}
```

Comment: How can you expect to capture "User" and "Base" variables using promise resolved **then** function. You have to run a call back inside **then** callback to update your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't see any data in the `console.log(hmc.User);` statement is because by the time this statement executes, the promise is not actually resolved (the request fetching users has not yet returned). Though digest cycle is invoked as a result of using `$timeout`, `hmc.User` does not have data yet.

Try invoking the digest cycle after the requests actually return in your `GeneralInit` method, and you should have the data available.

And also you should probably change your Get method to return a promise:

```
function UserSrv($http) {
  var User = {};

  var service = {
    getUser: Get
  };

  return service;

  function Get() {
    return $http.get('/user.json')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        User = data;
        console.log(User);
        return User;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your GeneralInit function is expecting getUser to return a promise, so just change it to this:

```
function UserSrv($http, $q) {
  var User={};
  var service = {
    getUser: Get,
    updateUser: Update,
    logoutUser: Logout
  };
  return service;

  function Get() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //return {"FirstName":"StaticName","LastName":'StaticLastName'}
    $http.get('/user.json')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          User = data;
          console.log(User);
          deferred.resolve(user);
          return User;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      });
      return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: not tested but I think that if you `return $http.get(etc, etc)` you can have the same results without creating a promise